# What is the significance of faded properties when using console.dir in Chrome Developer Tools Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, object

What does it mean when an object's property is slightly faded when using console.dir() in chrome's console.

For example, take a look at "top,width,worldVisible,x & y" in this screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of developer tools]

I've looked at the API reference here https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consoledirobject, but had no luck.

Thanks

Comment: Did those faded properties have values as soon as you expanded the object, or did you need to click a `(...)`?

Comment: @apsillers, in my example I needed to click them. Definitely related to the enumerable attribute in your answer though. Thanks

Comment: I asked because italic property names indicate a getter function, but italic getters also cause the `(...)` behavior. If you had an italic property without `(...)`, then that would be unusual. You did have it, though, so it's perfectly normal. (I added a little to my answer about that.)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Faded properties apper to indicate non-enumerable properties. If we do:

```
var a = {};
Object.defineProperties(a, {
    hello: { enumerable: false },
    world: { enumerable: true }
});
console.dir(a);
```

then we see that `hello` is faded, while `world` is not.

[image: console image showing faded <code>hello</code> property]

In your code, if you do `for(prop in obj) { console.log(prop); }` (where `obj` is whatever object you're showing us in your console screenshot), you'll see that only the faded properties are not enumerated.

You can also check this with `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, "worldVisible")`, which should return an object with an `enumerable: false` property.

Note that the *italics* on the property names indicate that the property value is defined by a getter function. (This also causes the value to display a `(...)` value before the function is run.) This is a totally separate issue from enumerability, which causes the names to be faded. You can have italic getter-defined properties that are not faded non-enumerable properties, and vice versa.

Comment: Ran a few tests, including the original object, and it looks like the right answer. Also means it was worth knowing after all, so I'm glad I asked.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find in the documentation any official explanation, but I have a good guess based on some tests that grayed out attributes are those that are defaults/set by the Javascript engine and not by the code itself.  Here are some examples:

## `length` in an Array

```
var foo = [1,2,3,45,1337];
console.dir(foo);
```

Gives in the console:

[image: console screenshot with length grayed out]

Notice that the indices are not grayed out but `length` and everything in `__proto__` is.

## prototyping

The code from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype#Examples

```
var Person = function() {
  this.canTalk = true;
};

Person.prototype.greet = function() {
  if (this.canTalk) {
    console.log('Hi, I am ' + this.name);
  }
};

var Employee = function(name, title) {
  Person.call(this);
  this.name = name;
  this.title = title;
};

Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee;

Employee.prototype.greet = function() {
  if (this.canTalk) {
    console.log('Hi, I am ' + this.name + ', the ' + this.title);
  }
};

var bob = new Employee('Bob', 'Builder');
bob.greet();
console.dir(bob);
```

Gives in the console:

[image]

There are a lot of interesting things here.  All instances of `greet` are not grayed out.  However everywhere `__proto__` is grayed out (probably because it is set by the engine to its prototype).  Also the overridden constructor from `Person` is grayed out, but the explicitly set constructor of `Employee` is not grayed out.

So I think there is a rough pattern here, which is that Chrom(e/ium) grays out properties that it thinks you're going to be less likely to care about, either because they were inherited or set by the engine as a construct of the language, but it seems its not perfect. (But who is, right?)  Another interesting thing to try is to <kbd>F12</kbd> and type `console.dir(window)`.  There you'll see almost everything grayed out except for things put into the global window namespace by the website's Javascript.