# What are these attributes that appear as 'light pink' in the Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Look at this image, from the Google Developer tools:

[image]

See that there are 2 shades of pink, `dark` and `light`.

I always thought that `light pink` where inherited attributes (prototype). Then, for the first time, I was debugging a library and I found `light pink` attributes that were not in the prototype. See `phones.addFields`.

The reason why I found these if because I did a `Object.assign` and some attributes were missing. So I realized that `light pink` attributes are not assigned in `Object.assign`.

So, what are these `light pink` attributes? How come `phones.addField` is `light pink`?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29821843/what-is-the-significance-of-faded-properties-when-using-console-dir-in-chrome-de

Comment: It has to do with the enumerable property of the field. Look at the accepted answer to the question @helllomatt linked - it has a good explanation