# I can't clone or assign properties from an Object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to copy some properties from another Object in JavaScript but failed.

The first thing I noticed is that some properties of an Object in Chromes console are slightly faded. I searched and find this question: [What is the significance of faded properties when using console.dir in Chrome Developer Tools Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29821843/what-is-the-significance-of-faded-properties-when-using-console-dir-in-chrome-de)

My task is to copy these properties and assign them with some new values. However, no matter I use `_.clone` or `_.cloneDeep` or `Object.assign()`, those "faded" properties are not included in new object.

[image: Use _.cloneDeep]
[image: Use Object.assign()]

Comment: Did you try: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))?

Comment: @Lain It returns a string without those faded properties, or, say unenumerable properties.

Comment: Alright, sorry for not being of any help this time. Should not be a string tho, yet the property problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

Because those "fade" properties are unenumerable. This means you can't interate over them. As a result, `Object.assign()` can not copy those properties.

```js
let a = {};
a.x = 1;
// define an unenumerable property
Object.defineProperty(a, 'y', {
  value: 2,
  enumerable: false
});
console.log(a, Object.assign({}, a)); //Object {x: 1, y: 2} Object {x: 1}
```

About the solution, you can retrieve the key list including unenumerable keys either by `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` or `Reflect.ownKeys`.

Comment: That's quite strange..I don't know why they became "unenumerable properties". I got this object data from a JSON api via superagent