# Declaring prototype function inside and outside a class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
class A {
    foo() {
        console.log("foo");
    }
}

class Mixin {
    insideFunction() {}
}

Mixin.prototype.outsideFunction = function() {};

Object.assign(A.prototype, Mixin.prototype);

let test = new A();
```

`test` and `A.prototype` have `outsideFunction` but not `insideFunction`.

What is the difference between declaring functions inside and outside the class? I thought they were the same thing but just syntactically different.

Additionally, when using `console.log(Mixin.prototype)` with Google Chrome, `outsideFunction` has a darker text color than everything else, including `insideFunction`. What is supposed to signify?

Comment: Here's some info on the faded text: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29827859/484780

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the difference between declaring functions inside and outside the class? I thought they were the same thing but just syntactically different.

Methods declared in ES6 classes are not enumerable. That means that if you would do:

```
for(let key in Mixin.prototype) console.log(key)
```

You will only see `outsideFunction` as that is a normal, enumerable property. As `Object.assign` does the same, you cannot use it to copy the unenumerable methods.

To copy them you could use [`getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames):

```
function deepAssign(target, ...objs) {
  for(const obj of objs) {
    for(const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)) {
      target[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Additionally, function expressions can't use `super`.