# Does window object have 2 different types or kinds of Properties in 2 different stacks?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

While if you try to `console.log(window)` on `chrome`, then you get a set of properties. That is fine.
But on further digging you find that from `A to Z` there are NOT 1 but 2 sets displaying one after another.

My question is if all these properties were of same kind then why listed in 2 different sets and not 1?Also, The first set of properties ordered `A to Z` are `properly visible and in black`.
The second set of properties ordered `A to Z` are `hazy visible or they seem blurry (which I think means something but I am not sure)`.

Can someone tell what is exact difference between these 2 sets of properties, why they are separated, and why we don't see `one consolidated ordered list`?

[image]

[image]

As, suggested by @Barmar, I went to the link [What is the significance of faded properties when using console.dir in Chrome Developer Tools Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29821843/what-is-the-significance-of-faded-properties-when-using-console-dir-in-chrome-de)
This suggests that issue is as "Chrome sets 2 blocks - based on Enumeration: true or false. I tried on 1 bold & 1 faded property, but both returned false. So, this link doesn't answer my question. Kindly, let me know --- **on What basis Chrome puts properties in 2 separated blocks**.

[image]

Comment: @barmar - So this means that "Google Chrome" stacks 2 set of properties -- 1 for enumerable: true & other for enumerable: false? Is this true??

Comment: Can someone reopen along with my updated comments?

Comment: Enumerable vs non-enumerable properties are a standard JavaScript feature. Chrome just shows them differently in the console.

Comment: It's more the properties that have been assigned with a `value`, e.g `Object.defineProperty( obj, key, { value: val } )` No matter the enumerability. The ones set with a getter will get logged as `(...)` + `get key: f get()`.